# Copying data between two Azure VMs in two VNETs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have two VMs each in a separate VNETs.

How can I copy files directly between them without leaving datacentre?

I'm running Google Drive on each of them, but that would be slow and incur costs.

Comment: Why not use Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: @BrianKnight - Too simple for me to thought about ;-) Could you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Blob Storage may be a good option. It's intra-datacentre and good for unstructured data such as files.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

Answer (score 0):

Connect two vnet, using vnet to vnet connectivity.
Then both of them will be accessible using DIP to each other. That will be the fastest.